# RadiusNetwork Android library and IBeaconReference not working

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon

Hi I have tried IbeaconReference, but I don't see any message in the edittext.

What I see in log cat is this:

```
01-17 12:16:13.354: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): startLeScan(): null
01-17 12:16:13.359: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
01-17 12:16:13.404: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-68
01-17 12:16:13.599: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-69
01-17 12:16:13.804: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-68
01-17 12:16:14.009: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:14.209: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:14.414: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:14.464: D/Callback(16608): attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
01-17 12:16:14.469: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): stopLeScan()
01-17 12:16:14.484: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): startLeScan(): null
01-17 12:16:14.489: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
01-17 12:16:14.634: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:14.819: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:15.029: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:15.239: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-66
01-17 12:16:15.444: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-66
01-17 12:16:15.594: D/Callback(16608): attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
01-17 12:16:15.594: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): stopLeScan()
01-17 12:16:15.604: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): startLeScan(): null
01-17 12:16:15.609: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
01-17 12:16:15.659: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-67
01-17 12:16:15.859: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-66
01-17 12:16:16.064: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-66
01-17 12:16:16.269: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-66
01-17 12:16:16.474: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-69
01-17 12:16:16.684: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): onScanResult() - Device=F9:70:D6:6F:1D:AA RSSI=-69
01-17 12:16:16.719: D/Callback(16608): attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
01-17 12:16:16.719: D/BluetoothAdapter(16608): stopLeScan()*
```

the method didRangeBeaconsInRegion is not called. Any idea?

Moreover I have added this to my manifest to launch the Service in the manifest:

android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService"

is this correct?

Comment: Based on the log, I see that:  1. The AndroidIBeaconService is detecting a single bluetooth LE device (although it isn't clear from the log that  it recognizes it as an iBeacon.)  2. It is repeatedly attempting to make a ranging callback from the AndroidIBeaconService to your app.  Three questions for you:  1. Are you using the reference app unmodified?  2. What kind of iBeacon are you using?  3. Can you see this iBeacon if you run the iBeacon Locate app in the Google Play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks I solved the issue by adding in the manifest what is said in radiusnetwork site.

```
<service android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:isolatedProcess="false"
        android:label="iBeacon"
        android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService">
    </service>    
    <service android:enabled="true" 
        android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">
            <meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter 
           android:priority="1" >
            <action android:name="eu.reply.engage.example.blebeacons.DID_RANGING" />
            <action android:name="eu.reply.engage.example.blebeacons.DID_MONITORING" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```